# Django: Render the template as query-results are calculated.(AJAX)

Tags: python, ajax, django

My django view contains atmost 20-25 functions.
Currently django takes atmost 11-12 seconds to render the complete template and until all the results have been calculated the template displaying is blank.

Is there any way so that I can make django render the sections of the template whose results is already calculated in view and the sections whose results are still being calculated can be rendered as when the view receives it.

Eg: Like if there is some view in which the ajax request displays the results as it receives the response.

Thanks!

Comment: Is not only about django.. Can be your css or javascript files as well... Anyway, Facebook has a interesting study case about how to render it .. https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

- In your view function, trigger asynchronous worker to calculate the results. Common worker frameworks include [Huey](http://huey.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and [Celery](http://celery.readthedocs.org/)
- Render the template, sans the result part. You can leave an [AJAX spinner there as a placeholder](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/).
- Have a JavaScript code which opens an AJAX call to another view which will render the actual results e.g. using [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). Trigger this in [window.load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) handler on the page.
- On your AJAX view, wait until the worker is done with the results (keep polling the result set). When completed, render the result template and return it to the AJAX caller.
- JavaScript code places the results returned from AJAX call on the page